# Navigation view на планшетах в ВК (Боковое меню)

Tags: android, анимация, android-animation, android-navigation-drawer

В приложении ВК боковое меню реализована нестандартным способом. Для планшетов элементы меню находятся всегда под рукой (в виде иконок к каждому пункту меню). Плюс можно открыть меню (посмотреть подписи пунктов меню), оно в свою очередь сдвигает весь контент справа (вместе с собой).

[image: Боковое меню ВК]

Вопрос. Как можно подобное реализовать, или может быть есть готовая библиотека?
В частности интересны следующие вещи:
- Как сделать, чтобы меню не закрывалось до конца(т.е. оставались иконки пунктов меню)
- Как запилить анимацию для исчезающего текста в пунктах меню.

Я пробовал гуглить и нашёл только как отcлеживать открытие и закрытие Navigation view:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {
@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

    int widthDrawer = (int) (drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset);
    contentView.setX(widthDrawer);
    contentView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth - widthDrawer, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}

@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
}
});
```

contentView - это все содержимое справа от меню (сдвигаю его). Но это не самый лучший вариант, наверно.

Answer (score -1):

Стандартная реализация Master/Detail Flow Navigation. Разделение главного экрана и смены информации, деталей. Результат достигается, разделением двух частей (возможно одной) на фрагменты, эта возможность появилась с Android 3.0. SDK 7+. Для этого есть template в Android studio, не надо придумывать, просто посмотрите как сделано и спроецируйте на свой проект со своей структурой. Анимации делать надо уже в самом конце, когда готова структура и налажена логика, иначе будете тянуть за собой зависимости при рефакторинге.